# Roll, Pitch Calculation Problem!

Tags: quadcopter

My problem is that when i hold my sensors (MPU9150) so that +y axis is downward, and y axis is on the horizontal plane, i expect that pitch = 90 degree,  and roll = 0 degree, but actually pitch = 90 degree, and roll = 160 degree. However, when roll = 90 degree and pitch = 0 degree (That is what i expect). Do you know what cause my problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most common definition of roll, pitch, yaw used in UAVs, when pitch=90deg you encounter what's called [gimbal Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock). Basically, when pitch=90deg you have infinite combinations of roll and yaw that will give you the same physical result.

Comment: Okie, Recently, i knew the reason like you said. Thanks anyway

Comment: @TuyenVoQuang ...which is why the MPU 9150 can also output quaternions.

Comment: Yes, i can know that, but how can we use quaternions to control the quadcopter is difficult so i choose Eulers.